# Connecting a sensor to the 5V pin shorts Arduino Nano

Tags: sensors, power, arduino-nano

I bought an ultrasonic distance sensor seen here: http://arduinobasics.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/arduinobasics-hc-sr04-ultrasonic-sensor.html?m=1. As per the wiring diagram I connect it to the ground and 5V pins on my Arduino Nano which is powered via USB.

As soon as I connect the 5V to the sensor it shorts and the lights on the Arduino go out and my laptop says 'usb surge too much power being drawn'. Do I need to add a resistor to the circuit? It all works fine and I get a result when the sensor is connected to the 3V3 pin but it does not ping properly.

I have tried using an external power supply via a breakout board as well as usb mains plug but both still short. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps the sensor has an internal short, or you're accidentally shorting wires? I just plugged my unit in exactly the way the referenced link shows, and using their code also on that side, I have no issues (with USB power or external PSU).

Comment: I tried both sensors and neither one works. I think i must be shorting wires somehow.

Comment: Can you show a pic of how you're doing things?